# Hiding button under condition in form in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This is my first post so don't judge me if i do something wrong because i'm still learning but i have a question i'm making a form and i have a problem. When i left the button without any extra stuff when i tested the form i got as many entries as many times i clicked the button so i used a code snippet from here in JS and made the button so it disappears, problem is when i don't fill the form correctly it doesn't send the entry, so the question is how can i add the condition in form so the button only disappears when every field is written correctly? I would add the whole html but it's houndreds of lines of code now since it's pretty much where i test things here is the form code though.

My other thought was to maybe try to edit the php code, but to be honest i have no knowledge of that because my friend made that.

I also searched google and here for some tips but couldn't find any, thanks for help in advance.

---

```js
$("#hideme").click(function(){
   $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<form method="post" action="thankyou.php" style="overflow:hidden" class="accident-form4">
    <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="pl">
    <div class="form-group required">
        <label for="name">Imię i nazwisko<span></span></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control inputToUpper" name="firstname" placeholder="Andrzej Kowalski" required="required" pattern=".*\S+.*" title="Wpisz swoje imię">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
        <label for="email">Email<span></span></label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" required="required" name="email" placeholder="np. andrzej.kowalski@gmail.com" title="Wpisz poprawny adres email!" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tel">Numer telefonu<span></span></label>
        <input type="text" name="tel" placeholder="079 1234 5678" class="form-control" required="required" size="12" value="">
    </div>
    <label for="hour">Preferowana godzina kontaktu</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="hour" placeholder="" title="" />
    <option>Dowolna</option>
    <option>Rano</option>
    <option>Po południu</option>
    <option>Wieczorem</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="lead" class="send" id="hideme" value="ROZPOCZNIJ CLAIM →">
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you want to validate the fields you'll need some validation code in client-side (JS probably) or in server side (PHP it seems), you probably should try a bit more in searching SO. See here for example, someone is trying to validate a form field in JS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506374/form-field-validation-javascript-empty-field. Add the `[javascript]`tag to your seaches on field validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply check the value of the required fields before hiding the button.

```
$("#hideme").click(function(){

    if (document.getElementsByName('firstname')[0].value != '' &&
        document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value != '' &&
        document.getElementsByName('tel')[0].value != '') {

        $(this).hide();

    }

});
```

or use your RegExp in Javascript again.

```
$("#hideme").click(function(){

    if (document.getElementsByName('firstname')[0].value.match (/.*\S+.*/) &&
        document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value.match (/[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/) &&
        document.getElementsByName('tel')[0].value.match (/[0-9]+/)) {

        $(this).hide();

    }

});
```

that should to the trick (but i didn't test it).

Comment: I think it would be better to just give the user a message like: "please input data xy in the username field" ... so you don't have to hide the button

Comment: It would be better to trim() the value to check for empty string. Instead of hiding the button. try to disable the button. That would be a better user experience.

Comment: It worked but it creates another problem, it's true , when the text fields are empty it doesn't hide the button but it doesn't include the situation in which the person types something wrong in their e-mail adress for example and than the button disappears anyway, it's good enaugh for me though so thank you very much.

Comment: @SpaceCowboy you can use your RegExp in Javascript to. Just check `if (str.match(regexp))` instead of `if (str != '')` [I edited my answer for that]

Comment: wow , this community is great , thanks guys , made my day , going to start tweaking it some more so maybe i get some funny results , one more time thanks :).